# Port number getting appended to base url when accessing the child web application resource through the main app in IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, webforms, .net-6.0

All,
I am hosting a dotnet core (net6) application under a webforms application in IIS 10.
Net core app is created as a web application under  the WebSite( Webforms). Please see below details
Accessing the net6 endpoint from the webforms app for some reason appends a port number to the base url as shown below

**Base Url**: https://baseurl.site

Accessing the netcore endpoint: https://baseurl.site/netcore/get

**Issue**: Accessing a netcore resource from webforms (parent app) causes port number getting appended to base url as shown here  https://baseurl.site:44340/netcore/get. This causes the request to fail. **This happens  only in production** and not in Dev or QA. If the user removes the port number form the base url, it works.

IIs settings
IIs version : 10
Windows Sever 2022

Net6 app is hosted in process

Both net6 and webforms apps run under two different application pools

Web.config for net6 had value for ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT **44340**, but removing this didn't fix the issue

Please see IIS settings and net6 **Program.cs, Startup.cs** for  the
WebSite and Web application

```
public class Program
    {        
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();            
            try
            {
                logger.Info("init main");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                //NLog: catch setup errors
                logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {                
                NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
            }

           
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseUrls();
                    webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();

                })
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.local.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);         
                })
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
                })
                .UseNLog(); 
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                
                options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
            });
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            services.AddSession();
    }
    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env){
    
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");                
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "subsite",
                    pattern: "netcore/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            app.UsePathBase("/netcore");
    
    
    }
```

I'd appreciate any directions as to where to look for. Spent couple hours on this already but to no avail.

[image]

[image]

Comment: An ASP.NET Core app on IIS under in-process mode does not need HTTP to HTTPS redirection, or similar tip to enforce its URLs. You will have to review your initialization code to remove such, and I think that should stop the URL from changing. Further troubleshooting requires access to your web app source code. BTW, deployment on IIS shouldn't use `Development` as environment as it hurts performance significantly.

Comment: Try accessing the netcore endpoint directly by typing the URL into the browser's address bar to see if that causes the port number to be appended to the url. If it can be accessed normally, the problem may be related to the webforms application.

Comment: @YurongDai, If I remove the port number and access the net core url, it works. Weird thing is that this is a problem only in production

Comment: @Lex Li, Added the Program.cs and Starup.cs code in the post

Comment: @YurongDai, I can access the netcore resource directly w/o the port number and it doesn't append it. It happens only when I go through the programmatic way.

Comment: You need to check the configuration of the dotnet core application, find the appsettings.json file which contains the application configuration settings. Make sure it is set to run on the same port as the webforms application in production.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. I am using the Ocelot gateway when the gateway is sending a request to microservice :443 is being appended. My URL: https://qa.abc.com:443/Myapp:443/Create 

This is working fine locally. I am using dot net core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Change the port number to 80 is http else 443 if https.
These are default ports and will not get appended in url